# No sound in bootstrap embedded video

Tags: html, audio, video

I have a problem with my code. Basically, video plays but I don't have any audio.

Could you tell me what could be wrong with this?

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="mov1.MOV" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<video>` instead:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="mov1.MOV" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Here is some additional documentation on using the `<video>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Unfortunately, now it looks like an image. It just freezes on start and that's it.

Comment: @K.Klik you may have issues with the format of that particular video. You can try a test video available here: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html and/or read about supported formats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

I found that extension MOV is not supported anymore. The simplest thing is to convert to a format that html5 supports.

Thank you for help